# MySQL Triggers using data from the trigger query

Tags: mysql, triggers

How do I use the data that was used to trigger the "trigger" in the trigger itself?

For example, lets assume we have a user (`user_id`) who created a new mission (`mission_id`) and therefore entered a new row in a table called `missions`.

Now I want to create a log in a table called `log` by using that specific `user_id` and `mission_id`.

What is that right syntax to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You access the pseudo rows [`OLD` and `NEW`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-trigger.html) to do this.
New contains the new data (e.g. Inserts and new Update data), and Old contains the outgoing data (Deletes and old values prior to an update).

```
CREATE TRIGGER t_missions
  BEFORE INSERT ON Missions
  FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
   INSERT INTO Log(user_id, mission_id) VALUES(new.user_id, new.mission_id);
END;
```

[SqlFiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6c26a0/1)

Comment: Can you please show me an example using the case I presented above?